# AC Recharge Failure - What did I do wrong?

Tags: honda, ac, accord, repair, air-compressor

I have a 2004 Honda Accord with AC that blows hot air. When failure started in the winter, the drivers side would blow hotter than the passenger side. Now they blow the same temperature: hotter than hell.

It seemed other people had similar issues online, and a recharge fixed it. I also talked to a technician at my local Honda dealer, and he said it sounds like a low refrigerant issue.

So I went out and bought a can of [AC Pro](http://acprocold.com/) (My car takes 19oz of R134A) and tried charging. When the compressor was off, it read high pressure. When the compressor turned on it dropped to 0psi, and stayed there. I used most of the can with no change in air temp.

EDIT: While recharging, the gauge came unscrewed from the nozzle, but stayed attached to the fill point. Not sure if this would cause the pressure to drop to 0psi, as it has a trigger to keep refrigerant from escaping/allow it to enter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No issue with recharge, just with a/c system

Finally took it to the Honda dealer, freon wasn't the issue, the issue was my condenser. A rock must have flown up and hit, as the system is now filled with rocks.

Answer (score 0):

I would start looking for a fairly large leak, by the sound of it. If it lost all pressure immediately upon running the compressor, it had to go somewhere. Many refrigerants have UV dye in them, and there are kits like [this one](https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/p/autocraft-uv-leak-detection-kit-ac992-uva-1cs/9220007-p?c3ch=PLA&c3nid=9220007-P&iv_=__iv_p_1_a_810678608_g_40371513285_w_pla-298755983213_h_9016882_ii__d_c_v__n_g_x_pla_y_6201684_f_online_o_9220007-P_z_US_i_en_j_298755983213_s__vi__&utm_source=ACQ&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=PLA&utm_content=shoppingcampaigns&gclid=CjwKEAjwvYPKBRCYr5GLgNCJ_jsSJABqwfw7sQOVYUagg2Vj653Csnhj1T7_kRLqYjVX6fyRRc_MDhoC8w7w_wcB) that include a black light that will illuminate the dye wherever it leaked out.

Comment: No leaks that I can see, especially supposing it would be that large. Should have clarified this in the original posting: While recharging the can came unscrewed. The nozzle stayed on the Low Pressure fill, so that wouldn't cause an issue, would it?

Comment: If there is a valve on the nozzle, I don't think it would, unless of course you were holding the valve open when it came off. Did you check for leaks with a black light or just by sight?

Comment: I bought a high mileage kit of AC Pro. It has a green dye to indicate leaks. I did not see any on the ground. When I got into the car to see if it was working, the air felt cooler briefly (and slightly). Thinking this could indicate a large leak or maybe pressure was lost when can was unscrewed.

Comment: if the high side pressure is not 0 and especially if it's high, I'd suspect air entering the system when you had the mishap with the can nozzle. Have you measured that yet? If you don't already know, you'll need a gauge designed to handle the high pressure in that circuit as well as to exercise caution when attaching it. It would be good to know what the pressure numbers are for each circuit, though.

Comment: That said, you wouldn't be low on refrigerant in the first place if there were not a leak somewhere, I would investigate that more.